# Why does the result cannot create when I run webdriver chrome on headless option

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, save, headless

When I run a selenium by a webdriver chrome with a headless option, I cannot get a correct result.
There was no error code.

But when I run a selenium by webdriver chrome without a headless option, I can get a correct result.

My python script funtion is

1. crawling a website.
2. click a check button.
3. click a save button by csv.

It works correctly when I run a webdriver chrome without headless option.
Thanks